# Let $f_n=\sqrt{n}e^{-nx}$ on $(0,1)$ does $\int_{0}^{1}f_nh \to 0$ for all $h \in L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, weak-convergence

Let $f_n=\sqrt{n}e^{-nx}$ on $(0,1)$ does $\int_{0}^{1}f_nh \to 0$ for all $h \in L^1$

This is the last part of a problem I am solving. These are the previous parts i have shown:

1) $f_n \to 0$ but not uniformly

2) $\|f_n\|_2 \to 0$

3) $f_n \rightharpoonup 0 $ In $L ^2$

I am pretty sure the statement is false but I do not know how to prove it. It is a weaker statement than weak convergence in $L^{\infty}$ so I don't have any standard theorems to apply.

Comment: For $h(x)=1/\sqrt{x}$, the limit is positive ($\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$, btw).

Comment: @ProfessorVector How did you find this counter example? I always have trouble finding them.

Comment: You could also prove it indirectly: The claim is equivalent to having $f_n \to 0$ in the weak star topology on $L^\infty$. But weak star convergent sequences are bounded. This is not the case for your sequence (boundedness in $L^\infty$ fails).